# Is it possible to change the font type?

Tags: eve-online

I find the fonts in eve online terrible for numbers, I find them very confusing especially in the market windows. Is there a way to change it? (I found nothing in the settings for that).

I know i can change the font size but I'd rather change the font type.

In case it matters, I play the linux version 1225328 but an answer for a windows/mac  version is 100% acceptable.

Comment: I'm 95% certain the font type can't be changed, but I'd love to be wrong. I totally understand the numbers thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the EVE Online font type. CCP used to let users edit the client files back in the early days of the game, but now the only thing you can change is the overview, and the overview tabs.

You can change the font size in the game chat, and the scaling of the game, but beyond that there is unfortunately nothing you can do.